# restore tensorflow model and use it for prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, save, tensorflow2.0, restore

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/adanet/blob/master/adanet/examples/tutorials/adanet_objective.ipynb#scrollTo=s5RuM582oxo_

I am modifying the code on the top to solve another regression problem( the modification is minor just changing the dataset with my dataset). once the network is optimized, I want to restore  the optimal nn and the coefs and use that for prediction. I am hoping to end up with y_prediction

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(r'\learn_mixture_weights\model.ckpt-60000.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, r'\learn_mixture_weights\model.ckpt-60000')
    tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_test)
    result = sess.run(tensor)
```

x_test is a numpy array.

currently, the result( print(result) ) give me exactly the input (tensor). how should i modify this to be able to get the prediction ( y_pred)?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Andrey modified the post to clarify the question.

Comment: @Behinoo what version of tensorflow are you using? Please show the output of ```print(tf.__version__)```.

Comment: @tornikeo  it is 2.3.0